# AngularJS why Not sending PUT on update using $resource

Tags: rest, angularjs

I am using [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) service to use CRUD operation on my REST API.

When customer.id is not set it is new record. so it send using Post Method

```
POST /info.json
```

Which is fine

But
When customer.id is set it also send using POST Method

```
POST /info.json/1
```

While I am expecting it to send using PUT Method something like this.

```
PUT /info.json/1
```

Why? Where I am doing wrong

```
$scope.save = function() {

            var customer = new Customer();
            customer.id = $scope.$id;

            customer.name = $scope.name;
            customer.username = $scope.username;
            customer.password = $scope.password;

            customer.$save({controller: "info", processor: ".json"}, function(data) {
                if (data.status)
                    $location.path("/");
                else
                    alert('Request Failed: ' + data.msg);

            }, function(data) {
                alert('Request Failed 2: ' + data.msg);
            }
            );

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it does not automatically select operation between update and create on ID.

So way around could be

```
if ($scope.$id != null)
            {
               customer.$update({controller: "info", processor: ".json"}, function(data) {
                    if (data.status)
                        $location.path("/");
                    else
                        alert('Request Failed: ' + data.msg);

                }, function(data) {
                    alert('Request Failed 2: ' + data.msg);
                }
                );

            } else {
                customer.$save({controller: "info", processor: ".json"}, function(data) {
                    if (data.status)
                        $location.path("/");
                    else
                        alert('Request Failed: ' + data.msg);

                }, function(data) {
                    alert('Request Failed 2: ' + data.msg);
                }
                );
            }
};
```

also add in resource, as it looks like angular does not have Update operation

```
update: {
            method: 'PUT',
        },
```

I don't know any better way to do this